# Ширина выпадающего списка Datagridviewcombobox

Tags: c#, winforms

На форме есть Datagridview1 (c# winforms vs2010 net4.0) с заранее определенными колонками через свойства, в который по кнопке "btn_AddRow" добавляется по одной строке (код ниже). Подскажите пожалуйста, как настроить ширину выпадающего списка "DataGridViewComboBoxCell Col" под самую длинную строку?

```
private void btn_AddRow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int index = Datagridview1.Rows.Count;
            index++;
            Datagridview1.Rows.Add();

            int nRowIndex = Datagridview1.Rows.Count - 1;

            string connStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source="c:\1.mdb";
            string query = "";
            query = "SELECT * FROM СПИСОК";
            OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(connStr);
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, cn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);

            ArrayList StringList = new ArrayList();
            foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
            {
                StringList.Add(item["Название"].ToString());
            }

            DataGridViewComboBoxCell Col = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)Datagridview1.Rows[nRowIndex].Cells["Column1"];
            Col.Items.Clear();
            Col.DataSource = StringList;
        }

ComboBox cb;
DataGridViewCell currentCell;

private void Datagridview1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (cb != null)
            {
                cb.SelectionChangeCommitted -= new EventHandler(cb_SelectionChangeCommitted);
            }
        }

        private void Datagridview1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Datagridview1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 1)
            {
                if (e.Control is ComboBox)
                {
                    cb = (ComboBox)e.Control;
                    if (cb != null)
                    {
                        cb.SelectionChangeCommitted += new EventHandler(cb_SelectionChangeCommitted);
                    }
                    currentCell = Datagridview1.CurrentCell;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Есть свойство [DropDownWidth](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcolumn.dropdownwidth?view=netframework-4.7.2). Но вот как сделать автоматическую подгонку ширины...

Comment: Я бы попробовал в процедуре btn_AddRow_Click в циклсе foreach у каждого элемента брать длину строки, найти среди них максимальную и изменить свойство DropDownWidth (с похожей проблемой сталкивался в excel, экспериментальным путем нашел коэф-т, на который нужно умножать длину строки для красивого отбражения)

Comment: @АмирЗакиров - Длину строки можно определить с помощью [TextRenderer.MeasureText](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.measuretext?view=netframework-4.7.2) или [Graphics.MeasureString](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.measurestring?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У класса `DataGridViewComboBoxCell` есть свойство [DropDown](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcell.dropdownwidth?view=netframework-4.8).

Для определения ширины строки используем метод [TextRenderer.MeasureText](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.measuretext?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Зададим ширину выпадающего комбобокса при добавлении новой строки:

```
private void btn_AddRow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // код опущен для краткости
    // ...

    DataGridViewComboBoxCell Col = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)Datagridview1.Rows[nRowIndex].Cells["Column1"];

    int max = 0;
    foreach (string item in StringList)
    {
        var size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(item, Col.Style.Font);
        max = Math.Max(max, size.Width);
    }
    Col.DropDownWidth = max;

    // ...
}
```

---

Если значения в комобоксе могут меняться, то код задания его ширины следует добавить в событие `EditingControlShowing`, например.